# svnserve not working with command="svnserve -t --tunnel-user=johndoe" in authorized_keys file

Tags: svn, ssh

This problem concerns using rssh as the shell (as specified in /etc/passwd) and svn+ssh to access the svn repository.   In the authorized_key file, on the remote svn server, my public key entry is:

```
command="svnserve -t --tunnel-user=johndoe" ssh-rsa  AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC36JxUAEsfRjXcnxFOhdedglzWMUwEfBnZSE/umuEgJ+myUyp1tAMIMTTNAz/NgWHF09PSj2Rd2qnqJjbCG/+AAQZ6lJ2xFn6tVmGaSob6wjnr/2PH6epx7im5r//qMt3UOQLgIha4igHOyzU/xNL2li8ODcHq2JOodONWkXGfpe/3uBaCBcQ2ufpSZr9XC3WOhBO73ch/CdBrpsZQYpIrcQtnSui32a3E7NSVRk6j42hmAXs6YG8w0Z+87yJriMaZUFARn+8SaDhKSpZDe6aJTb9EZ9grpaCgHb+Zs6sD7KCH/zLYFBAzlOedgd68ocp5xW+tXU0YQJOGoQ0Lc7SF johndoe@somesys1
```

I access the repository remotely using:

```
svn co svn+ssh://johndoe@192.168.1.11/home/somedir/repoName
```

This works as expected without the *--tunnel-user=johndoe*  in the entry. When used with the tunnel-user option, it gives the following error:

```
svn: E210002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL    
'svn+ssh://johndoe@192.168.1.11/home/someDir/repoName'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q 
option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

I did not find any debugging options to analyze further. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happened when you removed the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file?

Comment: @Kenster that was confusing. I did not see any -q option in the tunnels section. That line was commented. Instead I used the "o-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty" in the authorized_keys entry and found no need to use rssh anymore. It is documented [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) but I had missed it earlier.  Now ssh+svn is limited to svnserve and ssh cannot be used for any other command. Good enough for me. Thanks.